# PPL. How do i schedule several tasks on same worker thread?

Tags: c++, ppl, concurrency-runtime

I need to know how i can control on which worker thread `Concurrency::task` will run.

Imagine if i have following code:

```
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx;

    Concurrency::create_task([&mtx]
    {
        mtx.lock();
        std::cout << "Task 1. Thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        mtx.unlock();
    });

    Concurrency::create_task([&mtx]
    {
        mtx.lock();
        std::cout << "Task 2. Thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        mtx.unlock();
    });

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

How do i make sure that both tasks will run on **same** worker thread?

Comment: Use a task queue, push the tasks in it, and let the worker thread consume them.

Comment: @seccpur yes, you're right. But I'd like to do it using `Concurrency Runtime` library.

Comment: I thought that this library already has all the necessary tools for that. But somehow I'm unable to find them...